# rowSelectListener="#{bean.method}" throws javax.el.ELException: The class 'com.example.Bean' does not have the property 'method'

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I changed PrimeFaces JAR library to version 5 from version 2 and now get this exception.

> javax.servlet.ServletException: /home.xhtml: The class
>   'com.primefaces.sample.UserManagedBean' does not have the property
>   'onUserSelect'.
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606) root
>   cause
>
> javax.el.ELException: /home.xhtml: The class
>   'com.primefaces.sample.UserManagedBean' does not have the property
>   'onUserSelect'.

xhtm page contains `p:datatable`

```
rowSelectListener="#{userManagedBean.onUserSelect}"
rowUnselectListener="#{userManagedBean.onUserUnselect}"
```

Bean:

```
public void onUserSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    selectedUser = (User) event.getObject();
    System.out.println("selectedUser = " + selectedUser);
}

public void onUserUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
    selectedUser = null;
}
```

So why this doesn't work with PrimeFaces 5 while works with PrimeFaces 2 version?

Comment: Don't use any vendor's package hierarchy starting with the inverse of their domain name as you seem to have attempted knowingly or unknowingly - `com.primefaces` (though it is actually `org.primefaces`). It may lead to serious consequences as it may conflict while using different APIs of different vendors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check [Primefaces 5 user guide](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf), you'll notice that you cannot find the `rowSelectListener` attribute anywhere, but it existed in [Primefaces 2](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_2_2.pdf). Perhaps you want to take a look at the `onRowSelect` and `onRowUnselect` listeners of `<p:ajax>` events for `rowSelect` and `rowUnselect` (page 167 of Primefaces 5 user guide). See here also: [Primefaces tag rowSelectListener not found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084052/primefaces-tag-rowselectlistener-not-found)